# how to create a utils.py module

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, import, fileutils

I had a `def hello()` function in my `home/file.py`. I created a `home/common/utils.py`file and moved the function there.
Then I imported it like this: `from utils import hello` and the import in my file doesn't throw an error.

The path was also added to my settings.json automatically:

```
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "home/common"
  ]
```

However, when I run the code, it says `Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'file': No module named 'utils'`

So what's the correct way to create a utils module?

Comment: what's the file you do the import now? how does your modules directory structure look like? how do you execute the code? which module do you execute?

Comment: I do the import in ```home/file.py```. I created another folder in ```home/common/utils.py```. I execute the code (file.py) in aws lambda. @DariuszKrynicki

Answer (score 2):

in file.py:

from common.utils import hello

Comment: the error says ```No module named 'common'```

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-import-module-error-python/ @Jbd